# Removing continuation characters in the middle of a string in Python

Tags: python, line-breaks

The standard return value from the Google maps API looks like this - after conversion from bytes to a string:

```
b'{\n   "destination_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],\n   "origin_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],\n   "rows" : [\n      {\n         "elements" : [\n            {\n               "distance" : {\n                  "text" : "370 km",\n                  "value" : 369720\n               },\n               "duration" : {\n                  "text" : "3 hours 48 mins",\n                  "value" : 13672\n               },\n               "status" : "OK"\n            }\n         ]\n      }\n   ],\n   "status" : "OK"\n}\n'
```

In order to process is any further, I would like to remove all the line break characters first. However, I don't know how to do it

```
results_str.replace('\n', "")
```

won't work, .i.e., it returns the same string without replacing the '\n's, because of the line continuation character.

Same thing happens when I double the backslash

```
results_str.replace('\\n', "")
```

Any tips?

Comment: What do you mean with "won't work"? If I do `str.replace("\n", "")`, it returns the same string without all the `\n`s

Comment: Based on how the matter was resolved, the problem isn't anything to do with string escaping, but was simply failing to understand that `.replace` *creates a new string*. Closed as an appropriate duplicate. (Recommend deletion, because this makes very little sense as a signpost.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
results_str.replace('\n', "")
```

You're so close. The `\` is an escape character in string literals, so you must either double it up, or use a raw string:

```
results_str.replace('\\n', "") 
results_str.replace(r'\n', "")
```

Also remember that Python strings are immutable: `replace()` returns a new string, because the existing string cannot be modified. If you want to keep the changed string, you have to assign it to some name, such as the original name:

```
results_str = results_str.replace(r'\n', "")
```

Although you may want to process your data in a fashion that doesn't care about the newlines. That looks like JSON, so rather than trying to parse it yourself you should probably be using the Python `json` module.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried the doubling before: `results_str.replace('\\n', "")`, but for some reason it doesn't work. I will take a look at the JSON module

Comment: Wait, are you not reassigning the result back to `results_str`? I'll add some stuff about that.

Comment: @bluewoodtree: Do you do `results_str = results_str.replace('\\n', "")`?

Comment: omg. I am sorry, it's too early in the morning...embarrassing...vote me down and close this question... But thanks for the JSON recommendations, it looks very convenient

Answer (score 2):

This is a JSON response. Instead of trying to mess with the string, you should use the `json` module to parse the string:

```
import json
result = b'{\n   "destination_addresses" : ...'
obj = json.loads(obj.decode('utf-8'))
```