# how to get rid of \n from within strings in my array

Tags: python

code looks like this:

```
import stddraw
import sys
import stdio
#open the lexicon file
lexicon_input_file = open(sys.argv[1])
# copy the lexicon over from file
lexicon = lexicon_input_file.readlines()
#close the lexicon file
lexicon_input_file.close()
for i in range(len(lexicon)): #4000 words
    # breaks down entire lexicon into each element incremented from 0,1,2,3,4,..
    line_of_text = lexicon[i]
    line_without_newline = line_of_text.rstrip('\n')
print(lexicon)
```

terminal results look like this:

```
['the\n', 'be\n', 'and\n', 'of\n', 'a\n', 'in\n', 'to\n', 'have\n', 'it\n'.......
```

how do i get rid of \n from ends of elements. i tried rsplit but idk why it didnt work. im really new to coding!

Comment: I think this will work `line_of_text = line_of_text.rstrip('\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

try `lexicon.replace()`
ok, so per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001307/removing-continuation-characters-in-the-middle-of-a-string-in-python) thread, it looks like you need to use the "raw" character denoted by '\' or r()

So it should look like this.

```
lexicon.replace('\\n', "")
```

Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 0):

This should remove the '\n':

```
lexicon = [i.strip('\n') for i in lexicon]
print(lexicon)
```