# Removing newline in the middle of a string, with replace()

Tags: python, string, replace

After looking at this [Removing continuation characters in the middle of a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001307/removing-continuation-characters-in-the-middle-of-a-string-in-python) and documentation on strip() and replace() im am super confused why i cant remove this newline in the middle of a string?
I am taking into account that the \ is an escape character in string literals, and it still dont work with a raw string. What am i missing?

```
import re

data="Token\n Contract:\n 0x7e318f8d6560cd7457ddff8bad058d3073c1223f"
data2="Token\n Contract:\n 0x7e318f8d6560cd7457ddff8bad058d3073c1223f"

result = data.replace(r'\n', "")
result2 =data2.replace('\\n', "") 
print(result)
print(result2)
```

Comment: Because you **don't want to** take into account that it's an escape character; you want to specify a string that **actually does** have a newline in it - just like the source data does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to remove the literal string `\n`, not a newline. When you set `result`, you use a raw string, so escape sequences aren't processed. And when you set `result2`, you escape the backslash, so it's not an escape sequence.

Just use `'\n'` to make a newline.

```
data="Token\n Contract:\n 0x7e318f8d6560cd7457ddff8bad058d3073c1223f"
data2="Token\n Contract:\n 0x7e318f8d6560cd7457ddff8bad058d3073c1223f"

result = data.replace('\n', "")
result2 =data2.replace('\n', "") 
print(result)
print(result2)
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/WwWaA3)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex to remove the \n in the string you have and \n should be in single quote

```
import re
data="Token\n Contract:\n 0x7e318f8d6560cd7457ddff8bad058d3073c1223f"

print(re.sub(r'\n', '', data))
```

Outputof the above code

`Token Contract: 0x7e318f8d6560cd7457ddff8bad058d3073c1223f`

Hope this helps thanks